# At the end of Star Wars Rebels, how could these characters survive?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the last episode of Star Wars Rebels "*Family Reunion - and Farewell: Part II*" we see that:

> Ezra fights his way to Thrawn, and reveals that he arranged Mart to call the purrgil, who arrives and destroys Thrawn's fleet. The purrgil then grab Thrawn's flagship and ready to drag it to hyperspace. Despite pleas from his friends, they have to be convinced that they are defeated for good, and they jump away.

When

> the purrgil[image: the purrgil]

catch

> Thrawn,

they

> break all the windows of the ship. All windows of the control station where Ezra and Thrawn are located are broken... [image: Thrawn catched by the critters]

Then they

> flee into space in light speed.

As a result, when the ship enters space (and hyper space), how could the people on board survive?

> (Will Ezra act in the same way as Leia did in TLJ ? :) What about Thrawn ?)

Comment: Do we have any reason to believe they are alive? The last time we see them they're shooting off at lightspeed. Besides the claims of Sabine that he must be "out there somewhere"

Comment: At the end of the episod : "Accompanied by Ahsoka Tano, Sabine set out to find Ezra Bridger and bring him home."

Comment: How do we know Sabine is correct? Your assumptions, however, do turn out to be correct (by sheer coincidence) as said by David Filoni in an [interview](http://comicbook.com/starwars/2018/03/07/star-wars-rebels-finale-ezra-thrawn-survive/) `I’ll say this much: they’re not dead. Both of them survive, both Ezra and Thrawn I would say survive it.` The answer is therefore it is unknown and you'll have to wait for the new series.

Comment: Not confirmation, but supposition I guess. They're alive for now until someone else decides to kill them off before the next series starts.

Comment: Yers, they are alive for now... But how could it be possible ? The windows are broken, and they are in space... :/

Comment: I answered that above. The answer is unknown, that means there is no answer. You'll have to wait for later material to tell you. Any answer would be pure speculation, and not the good kind either.

Comment: Hmm. It's a toughie. I'm tempted to close as "[Future Works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)" but this is an intentional cliffhanger and it's the end of the show.

Comment: @Edlothiad Real life has *sheer coincidences* like that, but fiction doesn't. An episode endng this way is at least a fairly substantial hint to the audience.

Answer (score 4):

**Star Wars space doesn't work like real space.**

This isn't just shown in *The Last Jedi* with Leia's Spacewalk, but we also have plenty of older examples where brief exposure to a vacuum really isn't that big of a deal.

Putting aside the question of whether or not either of them survived (which I feel was intentionally left open to interpretation), they might have done so simply by making their way to an emergency cabinet of [breath masks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Breath_mask) and survive that way.

Most precedent for this is from *Empire Strikes Back*, which doesn't just introduce the breath masks but also introduces us to the [Mynocks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mynock) and [Exogorth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Exogorth), who both live in the vacuum of space. Of course I'm not implying that any of the characters in your spoiler block are actually silicon based, but it's clearly less of a big deal to be exposed to a vacuum in the Star Wars universe.

[image]

Once the immediate concern of oxygen is taken care of and the ships exit hyperspace they could go for a 'controlled landing' on the nearest planet with an atmosphere and await rescue.

[image]

Alternatively they could also have been rescued by the Purrgils, because who truly knows what a space whale is thinking?

Comment: Mynocks flew using their wings, and the environment we see them in is filled with some kind of foggy gas. So not a vacuum there.

Answer (score -3):

#### Space whales, I mean Purrgils are Deus ex machina

We know that they somehow survive in vacuum of open space. Arguably, they are not only ones that could do that - Exogorths, Mynocks and Leia are also capable of this. They could also somehow process [Clouzon-36](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clouzon-36) and use it as a fuel for hyperspace jumps. Their organic "hyperspace drives" and "navigational equipment" are also more advanced then those on ships in SW universe, since they could travel to Unknown Regions unaccessible to other sentient species, and even carry heavy load there. They are also so powerful it is trifle for them to destroy Imperial fleet full of Star Destroyers. Finally, they could probably communicate trough force at long distances, since Ezra summoned them somehow to help him in his fight.

Using godlike creatures to resolve seemingly unsolvable problem is an old plot device, and never considered to be much good, but there you have it . **If Purrgils could disable SD and carry it to hyperspace, who could say that they do not create protective Force bubble around it to save Thrawn and Ezra ?**

Comment: This seems like aimless guessing. Is there a *reason* to assume it was space whales?

Comment: @Valorum Since Disney introduced time travel, it could be anyone, but space whales were only one shown with appropriate power near by. We know that Ezra, Thrawn and rest of Imperials could not do it, so we are left with Purrgils.